# Approximating the sine function with polynomials using gaussian elimination

Tags: python, data-science, polynomials, approximation, polynomial-approximations

I'm trying to approximate the sine function over an interval with gaussian elimination using python. Using this code.

```
from copy import deepcopy
def convert_to_row_eschelon(A_, B_):
    A = deepcopy(A_)
    B = deepcopy(B_)
    dim = len(A)
    for cc in range(dim):
        # pivot_row = A[cc]
        for r in range(cc + 1, dim):
            leading_term = A[r][cc]
            for c in range(cc, dim):
                # print(A[r][c], A[r][cc])
                A[r][c] = A[r][c] - A[cc][c] * leading_term / A[cc][cc]
            B[r] = B[r] - B[cc] * leading_term / A[cc][cc]
    return A, B

def back_sub(matrix_pair):
    A = matrix_pair[0]
    B = matrix_pair[1]
    res = [None] * len(B)
    
    for i in range(len(B) - 1, -1, -1):
        def f(j):
            return A[i][j] * res[j]
        res[i] = (B[i] - sum([f(k) for k in range(i + 1, len(B))])) / A[i][i]
    return res


def gaussian_elimination(A, B):
    return back_sub(convert_to_row_eschelon(A, B))
A = [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 7],
      [23, 12, 12]
]
B = [4, 6, 7]
fig = 10
# print(convert_to_row_eschelon(A, B))
def make_polynomial(x_points, y_points):
    # A[x_point index used][degree]
    degree = len(x_points)
    A = []
    for i in range(degree):
        A.append([])
        for j in range(degree):
            A[i].append(x_points[i] ** j) # This is line 45 
    coeff = gaussian_elimination(A, y_points)
    def f(x):
        coeff_f = coeff
        res = 0
        for i in range(len(coeff_f)):
            res += x ** i * coeff_f[i]
        return res
    return f

def generate_x(start, finish, increment):
    x_points = []
    curr = start
    while curr < finish:
        x_points.append(curr)
        curr += increment
    return x_points
from math import sin, pi
start = 0 # These are the intervals
finish = 2 * pi
increment = 0.01
def test_func(x):
    return  sin(x)
# Creating the polynomial
x_val_f = generate_x(start, finish, increment)
x_val_test = generate_x(start, finish, 0.01)

f = make_polynomial(x_val_f, [test_func(i) for i in x_val_f])
print(f(3))
y_val_f = [f(i) for i in x_val_f]
y_val_test = [test_func(i) for i in x_val_test]
error = sum([abs(y_val_f[i] - y_val_test[i]) for i in range(len(y_val_f))]) / len(y_val_f)
print('average error : {}'.format(error))
# plotting f
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.plot(x_val_test, y_val_test, label = "test_func")
plt.scatter(x_val_f, y_val_f, label = "f(x)", s = 10)
plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.ylabel('y-axis')
plt.ylim(-1,1) 
plt.title('Graph')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But whenever I try making the increment smaller (to make the approximation function more accurately supposedly) python keeps giving me this error.

```
File "c:/Users/username/Desktop/Curve fitting.py", line 45, in make_polynomial
A[i].append(x_points[i] ** j)
        OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Is this just because I have too many points so `x_points[i] ** j` becomes too big? or have I made a mistake somewhere? and even if I do make it work by making the increment larger some of the points don't match up with the sin function.
[0.1 increment plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX1og.png). Test_func is the sine function and f is the approximation function.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Here is one more screenshot over an increment of 0.07 within the same interval as the one in the code. [0.07 Increment plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR0EE.png). If there are other things that might help with this please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such cases, it helps to use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) to find out what's going wrong. Or at the very least, use [try-except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) blocks to catch the exception and print your variables to see where your code explodes.

```
try:
    for i in range(degree):
        A.append([])
        for j in range(degree):
            A[i].append(x_points[i] ** j) # This is line 45 
except OverflowError:
    print(f"i = {i}; j = {j}")

### output: 
i = 310; j = 628
```

In this case, your code breaks when `i = 310` and `j = 628`. This is because `x_points[i] ** j = 3.10 ** 628`, which is too big to store in a double.

(Note that I specifically catch the `OverflowError` exception because the error message tells me that's the error that was raised. It is not a good idea to have an unfiltered `except` clause that catches *all* exceptions, because that can hide actual problems in your code and prevent other functionality such as exiting with Ctrl+C)